# React Dropzone Multiple Image at once in Tastypie

Tags: python, django, reactjs, tastypie, superagent

I have tried to **upload multiple image** using react-dropzone and tastypie.I am only able to store one images to the server using tastypie instead of multiple.Multiple image files are shown on console and django console but only the **last image among multiple images is only sent** to the server.

Here's my code

```
class MultipartResource(object):
    def deserialize(self, request, data, format=None):
        if not format:
            format = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json')

        if format == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
            return request.POST

        if format.startswith('multipart'):
            data = request.POST.copy()
            data.update(request.FILES)
            print('data is',data)
            return data
        return super(MultipartResource, self).deserialize(request, data, format)


    def put_detail(self, request, **kwargs):
        if request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE').startswith('multipart') and \
                not hasattr(request, '_body'):
            request._body = ''
        return super(MultipartResource,self).put_detail(request,**kwargs)

    def patch_detail(self, request, **kwargs):
        if request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', '').startswith('multipart/form-data') and not hasattr(request, '_body'):
             request._body = ''
        return super(MultipartResource, self).patch_detail(request, **kwargs)



class RentalResource(MultipartResource,ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Rental.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'rental'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post','put']
        fields = ['listingName','property','city','place','ownerName','room','water','amenities','price','summary','phoneNumber','email','image']
        filtering = { "property" : ALL , "room":ALL,"price":ALL}
        # authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
```

**Models.py**

```
class Rental(models.Model):
    ownerName = models.CharField(_("Owner's Name"),max_length=255, blank=True, null = True,
        help_text=_("Owner's Full Name"))
    email = models.CharField(max_length=120,blank=True, null=True)
    phoneNumber = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False,null=True,
        help_text=_("Phone number of contact person"))
    listingName =  models.CharField(_("Lisitng Name"), max_length=255, blank=False, null=True,
        help_text=_("Title of the rental space"))
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null= True,
        help_text=_("Description of the rental space"))
    property = models.CharField(_("Property type"),max_length=10,null=True)
    room = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("No of Rooms"), blank=False, null=True,
        help_text=_("Number of bedrooms available"))
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False,null=True,
        help_text=_("Rental price of the space per month"))
    city =  models.CharField(_("City"), max_length=255, blank=False, null=True,
        help_text=_("City of the rental space"))
    place =  models.CharField(_("Place"), max_length=255, blank=False, null=True,
        help_text=_("Place of the rental space"))
    water = models.CharField(_("water facilities"),max_length=50,null=True,
        help_text=_("Is there water facility?"))
    amenities = models.CharField(_("amenities"),max_length=100,null=True)
    phone_image = models.CharField(max_length=2048,blank=True,null=True,
        help_text=_("image form of the phone number"))
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.phoneNumber:
            print(self.phoneNumber)
            font = ImageFont.truetype(settings.PHONE_FONT,14)
            phone_image=Image.new("RGBA", (120,16),(255, 255, 255))
            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(phone_image) 
            draw.text((0, 0), self.phoneNumber, (0,0,0), font=font)
            byte_stream = BytesIO()
            phone_image.save(byte_stream, format="png")
            byte_stream.seek(0)

            self.phone_image = base64.b64encode(byte_stream.read()).decode()
        return super(Rental,self).save( *args, **kwargs)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.listingName

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Rent")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Rents")
```

**Listing.jsx**

```
var RenderPhotos = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
          files:[]
        };
    },

    onDrop(files) {
        console.log('Received files: ', files);
    this.setState({
        files: files
    });
    },

    showFiles() {
        const files = this.state.files || null;
        console.log('files',files);

        if (!files.length) {
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Dropped files: </h3>
                <ul className="gallery">
                    {
                        files.map((file, idx) => {
                            return (
                                <li className="col-md-3" key={idx}>
                                    <img src={file.preview} width={100}/>
                                    <div>{file.name}</div>
                                </li>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    },

    render: function () {
      return (
           <div>
                <h3>Photos can bring your space to life</h3>
                <p>Add photos of spaces to give more insight of your space </p>
                <hr/>
                <div className="col-md-12">
                <form method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
                  <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop}
                          style={style}
                          activeStyle={activeStyle}>
                    Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.
                </Dropzone>
                </form>
                {this.showFiles()}
                </div>
                <div className="row continueBtn text-right">
                    <button className="btn how-it-works pull-left" onClick={this.props.previousStep}>Back</button>
                    <button className="btn how-it-works" onClick={this.submitRent}>Next</button>
                </div>
          </div>
      );
    },

        submitRent: function(e) {
         // want to store the data so that when user reverts back to this form the data should be in same previous state 
          var req = request.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/rental/');
          var image = [];
          image = new FormData();
          var that = this;
          var index;
          for (index = 0; index < that.state.files.length; ++index) {
              console.log(that.state.files[index]);
              image.append('image',that.state.files[index]);
          }
          req.send(image);
          console.log('req is',req);
          req.end((err, res) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log('error', err);
            } else {
              console.log('success', res);

            }
          });


    }

});
```

What have i done mistake?Why only one image is sent instead of multiple image?

Comment: Did you check submitRent throw any error?

Comment: Nope.It does not throw any error.

Comment: I have checked on the console and it shows all the files .

Comment: you can see output on console  http://imgur.com/1UHYZAe

Comment: hmmm.. then you must check your Service logic is it store all the images which passed from client ?

Comment: Django console shows a list of images but only the last image is stored.I could not figure out it yet. You can see here the list of images in django console  http://imgur.com/0TtzDJ7

Comment: yes that is fine but I am asking to check API 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/rental/ I think the prob is in it

Comment: I am sorry i did not understand it.

Comment: on On submit you are call this API and take the images from that.state.files and append into FormData and POST the data with request that is fine but you have to also check from API side it takes the all data which you have passed in POST request and store it appropriate or not

Comment: I am not much more experience in using API . This is the first time i am using tastypie and i wanted to learn using it on my project.Can you help me on checking API?

Comment: ok in your API find the rental method and put the console.log and check over there

Comment: still did not get the idea. what should i write on the console,log ?

Comment: just write your good name and check it, it will show in console

Comment: yes it shows in console.

Comment: great now check over there images save logic is working fine when request happen from client side

Comment: yes it shows <QueryDict: {'image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: tushantKundli7.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: tushantKundli6.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: tushantKundli5.png (image/png)>]}>
[18/Jan/2016 09:33:22]"POST /api/v1/rental/ HTTP/1.1" 201 0

Comment: Great Go ahead you will find the prob

Answer (score 0):

If multiple images show up in Django then multiple images are being sent to the server. The reason only one image is being saved is:

1. The key lookups tastypie does on the deserialized data will only return a single item. You'll probably have to override `dehydrate_image` on your resource and call `getlist` if bundle.data is a QueryDict if you want a list of files.
2. Rental.image is an ImageField, which can only store a single file. To store multiple files you'll need to change your schema.

Comment: Do you mean to say i have to create a separate table for image ?

Comment: Yes, you'll need a separate table.